# The performance of IFNULL in MySQL on large datasets

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm breaking my head over a 'product which can have multiple variants' schema for my MySQL database design.

I want to have a table called `base_products` and `products`. Every `product` belongs to a `base_product`.

`product` should inherit  columns from `base_product` but also has some columns which are named the same. The column data of `products` will override the `base_products` columns but only if the column on `products` is not NULL.

The query for retrieving products would theoretically look something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    IFNULL(p.sku, _p.sku) AS sku,
    IFNULL(p.ean, _p.ean) AS ean,
    IFNULL(p.weight, _p.weight) AS weight
    IFNULL(p.unit_id, _p.unit_id) AS unit_id
FROM products AS p
JOIN base_products as _p ON p.id = _p.product_id
WHERE IFNULL(p.weight, _p.weight) > 500
```

In this case `IFNULL` is used for querying potentially very large tables.

Would the use of `IFNULL` be acceptable in this context? Or will this break performance when querying large datasets?

Comment: Create some hugh dummy datas and execute EXPLAIN to know how it will perform.

Comment: I would caution against using any aspect of sql as if it were an inheritance system

Comment: @user2864740 I should add that this also has to work `WHERE IFNULL(p.name, _p.name) = 'something'`. It should really make a choice which colum to do the where on based on the presence of data in `products`

Comment: @user2864740 your equivalence assertion is logically incorrect.  `IFNULL(p.weight,_p.weight) > 500` **is not equivalent** to `p.weight > 500 OR _p.weight > 500`.  The equivalent expression is actually `(p.weight > 500) OR (_p.weight > 500 AND p.weight IS NULL)`.  For example, the expression `IFNULL(250,750) > 500` **is in fact** `FALSE`, but using your expression, `250 > 500 OR 750 > 500` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 2):

First, I much prefer `coalesce()`, because that is the ANSI standard function:

```
SELECT p.id,
       COALESCE(p.sku, _p.sku) AS sku,
       COALESCE(p.ean, _p.ean) AS ean,
       COALESCE(p.weight, _p.weight) AS weight
       COALESCE(p.unit_id, _p.unit_id) AS unit_id
FROM products p JOIN
     base_products _p
     ON p.id = _p.product_id
WHERE COALESCE(p.weight, _p.weight) > 500;
```

However, that has nothing to do with performance.

The performance issues in this query have almost nothing to do with the `COALESCE()` (or `IFNULL()`).  That is merely a function call.  The real issues are the `JOIN` and the `WHERE` -- these involve the movement of data.  The `JOIN` is easy:  just be sure that the columns used for the `JOIN` have indexes.

The `WHERE` is tricky.  If it filters out lots of rows, there might be some other alternatives, but they are more complicated.  I would focus on the `JOIN` indexes.

Comment: Thank you! Just picking your brain.. Is there any good way to achieve this inheritance with overriding columns and having them in the where clause while maintaining good performance? Or would it be better to do this selection of data in my application code and just accept the presence of duplicate data in the `products` table

Comment: @Boyd . . . I think your method is fine.  If you actually have performance problems, then address them.  Otherwise, you can use a view to avoid repetitive code.